# Install R failed in Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, r

Please can someone provide assistance with this issue

```
    sudo apt install r-base-core
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you 
    have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the 
    unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been 
    created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    r-base-core : Depends: libtcl8.6 (>= 8.6.0) but it is not 
    installable
           Depends: libtk8.6 (>= 8.6.0) but it is not installable
           Recommends: r-recommended but it is not going to be 
    installed
          Recommends: r-base-dev but it is not going to be 
    installed
           Recommends: r-doc-html but it is not going to be 
    installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It would be greatly appreciated!Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! but it actually did not solve my issue. When i try to install r i get this output: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-recommended (= 3.6.3-2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Still not sure how to fix it-i follow all step from proposed solution

Comment: Thank you for prompt response and willingness to help! after attempting to apply the solutions from link you have sent, i was not managed to solve issue with broken packages..but i did manage to install R, now i have problem with Rstudio. Someone posted similar issue  - so will try to fix with already proposed solutions. Thanks once again!